# Give an example of $A,B$ in $G$ where $AB$ is not a group and prove this.

Tags: group-theory

Give an example of $A,B$ in $G$ where $AB$ is not a group and prove this.

I have just proved that $AB$ is a group iff $AB=BA$ and this is the next part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since (as you have shown) abelian groups don't provide examples, you have to look among non-abelian ones. Take the smallest such group, $S_3$ the symmetric group on 3 points, as an example for $G$, and let $A=<(12)>$ and $B=<(13)>$. Then confirm that $AB$ is not a subgroup of $G$, i.e. not a group.

Comment: oh thats really simple, thank you, i was totally overcomplicating it!